# Ajax script doesn't work well while typing(keyup)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an input used to search. User starts typing and while typing, a number of results that are related with the typed string are shown in a table.

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchinput" onkeyup="Search()" placeholder="Search...">
```

My Javascript function:

```
function Search() {
  var value = $("#searchinput").val().toLowerCase().trim();
  if (value == '') {
    $("div#results").html('');
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'getresults.php',
      data: {
        values: value
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $("div#results").html(response);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If user types search terms fast then user gets the desired results. If you type slowly then it gets results and after a couple seconds it's like it breaks and shows other results (maybe from previously pressed key?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the autocomplete feature of jquery to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing a debounce, this will only fire a request after 250ms of inactivity.

```
$.debounce(250, function(e) {
    console.log("It works!");
})
```

Here is the debounce function i referenced
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js